# password_verify gives a returns wrong account details

Tags: php, sql, security, passwords

My password_verify() gives always a wrong accounts details, but the details are correct.
My snippet:

```
    include('Application/Bootstrap.php'); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location: '.$config['website']['url'].'/me'); // Use this if the user HAS to login.
    }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password']) {
        echo 'Je moet een gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord invullen om in te loggen.';
    }
    else {

        $check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);

                 if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { //I try $password AND $_POST['password']
                 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                header("Location: /me");
                exit;                   
            } 
            else {
                // ALS HET NIET KLOPT!!!!
                echo 'Je gegevens kloppen niet.';               }
        }
    }
```

Can somebody help me? I have already search the whole internet. But I can't find it. I have my database column varcher increased to 255. If you ask of my register is wrong, that's not so. Snippet:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO users
            (username,password,mail,auth_ticket,motto,ip_reg)
            VALUES ('$username', '".password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."', '$mail', '$ticket', '$motto', '$ip')") or die($db->error);
```

The cost is '10'.

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: You're storing the hashed password, but try to match the column `and password = '".$password."'` against the plain password.

Comment: You should simply use `$check = $db->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."');` for your password query; but why aren't you using bind vars for your database query?

Comment: You should also be checking that the database query has actually returned a result, ie if $row is actually a valid result and not false

Comment: What do I now correctly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the password twice, the first time you check it in the SQL query:

```
$check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
                                                                         |< remove this part          >|
```

This query will find only users with a given username **and** with a given password. But because only a hash of the password was stored, this query will never find a row. You should remove the check with the password and only search for a user by username.

To be safe from SQL-injection you should also use [parametrized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
...
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
{
  ...
}
$result->close();
```

Comment: @user3902511 - And what is the error? Did you check the content of the row variable `var_dump($row)` ? You can turn on error reporting to find other problems, place this line at the begin of the file `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: If I do var_dump($row); I get: NULL Je gegevens kloppen niet.

Comment: @user3902511 - If you executed the query and afterwards the `$row` is null, then the database could not find any row matching the query. I wrote an example (without error handling) with prepared statements, note that quotes '' or calling real_escape_string() are not necessary this way. Make sure that `$_POST['password']` really contains the input value, maybe your HTML contains a field with a different name.